# Changing delay for setTimeout loop

Tags: javascript

Currently I have a string of letters and numbers that get split into an array and then display one by one separated by a set amount of time defined by the user. I've run into a problem though, before I initialize myFunction(), I am able to set the number of letters/numbers that are displayed per minute, but once the function is running I cannot change the speed. How would I modify my code to allow me to change the speed up or down while the function is already running.

```js
var string = "33 a 52 20 82 86 81 7 96 86 c 25 29 44 64 77 D 40 32 55 50 L 65 48 35 21 85 y 46 88 63 55 u 48 65 6 17 37 e 51 53 47 50 a 16 72 M 64 80 P 54 w 43 f 4 67 32 55 79 29 62 11 32 g 47 78 38 42 59 92 x 15 43 61 92 50 57 31 Z 84 69 80 32 9 m 98 22 83 19 12 21 37 28 63 42 73 88 84 75 60";

function myFunction() { 
    
  var array = string.split(' ');
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      
    var delay = 60000/(document.getElementById('numPerMinute').value);   
      
    (function (str) {      
      setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById("displayResults").innerHTML = str;
      }, delay * i);
    })(array[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Run</button>
<input type="number" id="numPerMinute"/> 
<div id="displayResults"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @Arrow, does that allow me to change the speed while the function runs?

Comment: Use a recursive approach where each callback sets the timeout for the next one, instead of scheduling all of them at once in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke a new timeout recursively after the previous one has finished. This way the delay is calculated each time just before a new timeout starts.

```js
var string = '33 a 52 20 82 86 81 7 96 86 c 25 29 44 64 77 D 40 32 55 50 L 65 48 35 21 85 y 46 88 63 55 u 48 65 6 17 37 e 51 53 47 50 a 16 72 M 64 80 P 54 w 43 f 4 67 32 55 79 29 62 11 32 g 47 78 38 42 59 92 x 15 43 61 92 50 57 31 Z 84 69 80 32 9 m 98 22 83 19 12 21 37 28 63 42 73 88 84 75 60';

var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {

  var results = document.getElementById('displayResults');
  var array = string.split(' ');

  this.disabled = true;
  results.innerHTML = '...';
  
  function startDelay() {

    var numPerMinute = parseInt(document.getElementById('numPerMinute').value);
    if (!numPerMinute) {
      // Invalid input
      btn.disabled = false;
      return;
    }

    var delay = 60000 / numPerMinute;

    setTimeout(function() {
      results.innerHTML = array.shift();
      startDelay();
    }, delay);
  }

  startDelay();
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Run</button>
<input id="numPerMinute" type="number" value="30">
<div id="displayResults"></div>
```